# VBA Error 424 Object Required on a Lookup

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I've read multiple threads but still can't figure this out

This Lookup reads inputItemType from code further above, same SUB.

I'm trying to substract 1 from the Stock column of different tables, depending on the inputItemType.

```
' Substract Stock


If inputItemType = "Vinyl" Then
    Worksheets("Vinyl Table").Activate
    Dim lookupVRange As Range
    Set lookupVRange = Range("D:D")
    Dim resultVRange As Range
    Set resultVRange = Range("S:S")
    Dim vinylStock As Range
 
    vinylStock = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(inputItemID, Range("D:D"), Range("S:S")).Select
    vinylStock = vinylStock - 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried changing the faulty line for

```
Set resultVRange = Range("S:S")
 Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(inputItemID, lookupVRange, resultVRange).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(inputItemID, lookupVRange, resultVRange).Value - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

*VLookup* does not return a `Range` object, and you would want to use a `Variant` to trap a possible error.

You also want to try an trap an error in case VLookup failed to find a Match.

***Modified Code:***

```
Dim vinylStock As Variant

vinylStock = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(inputItemID, lookupVRange, resultVRange)
If Not IsError(vinylStock) Then ' verify VLookup was successful
   vinylStock = vinylStock - 1
End If
```

Comment: Thank you... The error is gone, however I see no change to the existing values on the stock, the subtraction is not happening. Aren't you supposed to select the .Value? vinylStock = vinylStock - 1  Is this not simply assigning the Vlookup result to a row above?